# Migration from Tomcat 7 to JBoss7.1

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, struts2, jboss, jboss7.x

Previously I was working on an application which is running on Tomcat 7 server but now I wan to run it on JBoss7.1 Server . But when I am trying to run it. It is showing me this kind of error. I am not getting what is it and how to resolve it. I searched on internet but could not find valuable response.

**My log on JBoss is:**

```
09:52:08,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "WEB-ERP.war"
09:52:12,994 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."WEB-ERP.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."WEB-ERP.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "WEB-ERP.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_12-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_12-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_12-ea]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.ConditionalTagBase with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.WEB-ERP.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/struts/util/MessageResources;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_12-ea]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_12-ea]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_12-ea]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources from [Module "deployment.WEB-ERP.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

09:52:13,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:52:13,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "WEB-ERP.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"WEB-ERP.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"WEB-ERP.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"WEB-ERP.war\""}}
09:52:13,056 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 10052ms - Started 140 of 218 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
09:52:13,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment WEB-ERP.war in 51ms
09:52:13,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."WEB-ERP.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."WEB-ERP.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "WEB-ERP.war"

09:52:13,116 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"WEB-ERP.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"WEB-ERP.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"WEB-ERP.war\""}}}}
```

And the error message I am getting is `The requested resource (/StrutsHelloWorld/) is not available.`   And I am working on Struts 2 & Hibernate 4 Integration application which is working fine on Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Struts classes: they were probably in the Tomcat class path. You should make sure the Struts libraries are added to your WAR file.

Comment: Put the struts jars in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder before packaging the web application then redeploy it to JBoss.

Comment: i am not crating any war file it is the simple web project inside the eclipse id. jar files are already in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Well, looking at your errors it looks like Eclipse is creating a WAR file (`deployment.WEB-ERP.war`) to deploy to JBoss and isn't including some or all of the folders in the `WEB-INF\lib` directory. Not sure what tools you're using to run in JBoss but you'll need to check to see what files are being included in the output WAR file (if it is indeed generating a WAR file) or what the classpath is (if it is launching JBoss with the unpacked directory as the web application).

Answer (score 0):

The project has classpath dependency to the Struts1 libraries. You should either include Struts1 libraries or exclude dependencies that reference to `org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources`. This class is found in the following jar:

- struts-core-1.3.10.jar